# malloc error when using std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I've decided to parallelize a huge program I wrote and eventually I came across the new C++11 smart pointers.

I had a routine that should be executed many times (usually above 1000 times) that is somewhat expensive. It was ran in a dead simple for loop, what I did was to install this for loop in a method which would be ran by some worker threads.

Did it so, made some parameters wrapped by a `std::shared_ptr`, cared for race conditions, everything seemed fine.

But now, some times, process will be aborted and I am given one of the following errors:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:
>   SIGSEGV)

or

> malloc.c:2395: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) &&
>   old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse
>   (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

All of these errors occur while the parallel for is ongoing; not before, not right in the beginning, not in the end, but somewhere in between, which smells me like a race condition not covered.

The program is huge, but I created a miniature of it that is able to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <thread>
#include <set>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

namespace std {
    template <>
    struct hash<std::multiset<unsigned long>>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const std::multiset<unsigned long>& k) const
        {
            std::size_t r = 0;

            bool shift = false;
            for (auto&& it : k) {
                r = (r >> !shift) ^ (std::hash<unsigned long>()(it) << shift);
                shift = !shift;
            }

            return r;
        }
    };
}

typedef std::unordered_map<std::multiset<unsigned long>, int*> graphmap;

std::multiset<unsigned long>* bar(int pos) {
    std::multiset<unsigned long> *label = new std::multiset<unsigned long>;

    label->insert(pos%5);
    label->insert(pos%2);

    return label;
}

void foo(std::shared_ptr<graphmap> &kSubgraphs, int pos) {
    int *v = (*kSubgraphs)[*bar(pos)];

    if(v == nullptr) {
        v = new int[pos+1]();
        v[0]++;
    } else {
        v[pos]++;
    }
}

void worker(std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_int> *counter, int n, std::shared_ptr<graphmap> *kSubgraphs)
{
    for (int pos = (*counter)->fetch_add(1); pos <= n; pos = (*counter)->fetch_add(1)) {
        if (pos%100==0) std::cout << pos << std::endl;
        foo(*kSubgraphs, pos);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 1000;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::shared_ptr<graphmap> kSubgraphs = std::make_shared<graphmap>();
    std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_int> counter = std::make_shared<std::atomic_int>(0);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        foo(kSubgraphs, n);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(worker, &counter, n, &kSubgraphs));
    }

    for(auto& th : threads) th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

This code basically mimics the behavior of the original code, which is to use an *unordered_map* keyed by a *multiset* with values that are pointers to *int* arrays. First some keys are inserted and the array initialized (maybe the problem is caused by the way I am initializing it?) and finally the worker threads run to update a unique position of the array of an entry of the *unordered_map*.

Two threads may access the same map entry simultaneously, but they will never write to the same index of the array at the same time.

Different from the original code, this code won't throw any errors when running over internet compilers such as ideone.com, I also tried to run it from CLion ide and no errors will occur (maybe it can occur errors if one tries enough times), but I got similar error as the original when running from the command line multiple times. I compiled it with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -o test.exe test.cpp
```

And after running several times it eventually gives this error:

```
*** Error in `./test.exe': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000006a2d30 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7fccc9d4f725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7fccc9d57f4a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fccc9d5babc]
./test.exe[0x404e9e]
./test.exe[0x40431b]
./test.exe[0x4045ed]
./test.exe[0x407c6c]
./test.exe[0x4078d6]
./test.exe[0x40742a]
./test.exe[0x40869e]
./test.exe[0x4086be]
./test.exe[0x4085dd]
./test.exe[0x40842d]
./test.exe[0x4023a2]
./test.exe[0x401d55]
./test.exe[0x401c4a]
./test.exe[0x401c66]
./test.exe[0x401702]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fccc9cf8830]
./test.exe[0x401199]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0040f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 12202697                           /home/rodrigo/test.exe
0060e000-0060f000 r--p 0000e000 08:05 12202697                           /home/rodrigo/test.exe
0060f000-00610000 rw-p 0000f000 08:05 12202697                           /home/rodrigo/test.exe
00691000-006c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fcca8000000-7fcca8089000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcca8089000-7fccac000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccb0000000-7fccb008b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccb008b000-7fccb4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccb8000000-7fccb8089000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccb8089000-7fccbc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc0000000-7fccc007c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc007c000-7fccc4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc79cb000-7fccc79cc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc79cc000-7fccc81cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc81cc000-7fccc81cd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc81cd000-7fccc89cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc89cd000-7fccc89ce000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc89ce000-7fccc91ce000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc91ce000-7fccc91cf000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc91cf000-7fccc99cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccc99cf000-7fccc9ad7000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24126366                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fccc9ad7000-7fccc9cd6000 ---p 00108000 08:05 24126366                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fccc9cd6000-7fccc9cd7000 r--p 00107000 08:05 24126366                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fccc9cd7000-7fccc9cd8000 rw-p 00108000 08:05 24126366                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fccc9cd8000-7fccc9e98000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24126374                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fccc9e98000-7fccca097000 ---p 001c0000 08:05 24126374                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fccca097000-7fccca09b000 r--p 001bf000 08:05 24126374                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fccca09b000-7fccca09d000 rw-p 001c3000 08:05 24126374                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fccca09d000-7fccca0a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccca0a1000-7fccca0b9000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24126373                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fccca0b9000-7fccca2b8000 ---p 00018000 08:05 24126373                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fccca2b8000-7fccca2b9000 r--p 00017000 08:05 24126373                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fccca2b9000-7fccca2ba000 rw-p 00018000 08:05 24126373                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fccca2ba000-7fccca2be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccca2be000-7fccca2d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24121519                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fccca2d4000-7fccca4d3000 ---p 00016000 08:05 24121519                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fccca4d3000-7fccca4d4000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 24121519                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fccca4d4000-7fccca646000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6029347                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fccca646000-7fccca846000 ---p 00172000 08:05 6029347                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fccca846000-7fccca850000 r--p 00172000 08:05 6029347                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fccca850000-7fccca852000 rw-p 0017c000 08:05 6029347                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fccca852000-7fccca856000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fccca856000-7fccca87c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24126370                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fcccaa44000-7fcccaa4a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcccaa78000-7fcccaa7b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcccaa7b000-7fcccaa7c000 r--p 00025000 08:05 24126370                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fcccaa7c000-7fcccaa7d000 rw-p 00026000 08:05 24126370                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fcccaa7d000-7fcccaa7e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc6b1c8000-7ffc6b1e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc6b1fa000-7ffc6b1fc000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc6b1fc000-7ffc6b1fe000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
[1]    26639 abort (core dumped)  ./test.exe
```

At last, when running the original code with debug mode on in CLion set up to capture Exceptions as breakpoints, it shows a Signal interruption of `SIGBUS(Bus error)` or a `SIGSEGV(Segmentation fault)` sometimes and last line of code executed before the interruption maps to the line:

```
    int *v = (*kSubgraphs)[*bar(pos)];
```

in the `foo` function of the code presented here.

I am a little bit lost with this one. My strongest assumption is that I am using smart pointers the wrong way, despite I do not see where.

Comment: I might be terribly wrong here, but where exactly is the thread safety? Shared_ptr does not guarantee it, at least not that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior, because you access the object pointed to by `kSubgraphs` from different threads without mutual exclusion. This happens in this line of code in function `foo`, which is called from your thread function `worker`:

```
int *v = (*kSubgraphs)[*bar(pos)];
```

I can't guess why you think `shared_ptr` would help your case in any way. The way you do, it is totally pointless to wrap your objects in `shared_ptr`.

`shared_ptr` is used when ownership of your objects is shared from different other objects. It has nothing to do with "sharing objects between threads".

Comment: What  about std::atomic_store and std::atomic_load?

Comment: Very well, as I suspected, I took for wrong the behavior of `std::shared_ptr`. I though that a shared pointer would allocate heap memory in a sense that it is ok for other threads to access this memory position (now I think there is no need for declaring in any way that a memory region will be accessed by other threads). Still, curious why my code summons undefined behavior, since I see no need to have a read lock, which is the case of the mentioned line of code, as it's clear that at the point threads start dealing with *kSubgraphs* no more entries will ever be added to it.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins, [the std::unordered_map operator `[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) is non-const and it inserts the key if it does not exist. It's a source for race conditions and so on.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins The loop in `main` inserts elements in `kSubgraphs` corresponding to hash values of multisets {0,0}, {1,1}, {0,2}, {1,3}, and {0,4}. But when the `foo` is called with pos == 5 from a thread, an element for {0,1} is inserted without mutual exclusion. Other values of pos insert elements for {1,2}, {0,3}, and {1,4} from the threads.

Comment: Thanks @megabyte1024 ! I didn't watch for operator `[]` being non-const. Moved to using `.at()` when calling `foo` from the worker threads and now it is working.

Comment: Thanks you @j6t . Indeed the example code is broken there, despite this behavior does not occur on the original one, my bad. Thank you a lot, you saved me some good hours of head smashing.